# QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream

Tags: php, quickbooks

I am using Consolibyte PHP SDK for QuickBooks Desktop. I have got this error when I have tried to get Bills from the QuickBooks Desktop-

```
0x80040400:QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.
```

The XML Request is given below and I think the XML is valid and the endpoint BillQuery supports IteratiorID-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?qbxml version="13.0"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <BillQueryRq  iterator="Start"   requestID="1">
                    <MaxReturned>10</MaxReturned>
                    <FromModifiedDate>1983-01-02T12:01:01</FromModifiedDate>
                    <IncludeLineItems>true</IncludeLineItems>
                    <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
                </BillQueryRq>  
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go look at the OSR documentation:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

The `FromModifiedDate` filter is very clearly wrapped inside another XML node:

```
<ModifiedDateRangeFilter> <!-- optional -->
  <FromModifiedDate >DATETIMETYPE</FromModifiedDate> <!-- optional -->
  <ToModifiedDate >DATETIMETYPE</ToModifiedDate> <!-- optional -->
</ModifiedDateRangeFilter>
```

Fix your XML so that it conforms to what the OSR shows.

If you'd taken the time to search, you'd find that there is an `XML Validator` tool included with the SDK which will tell you exactly what the error in your XML is.