# I am creating TimeTrackingAddRq XML and getting error?

Tags: quickbooks

Error: "QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream."

Not able to find out what the actual error.

Here is XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
<TimeTrackingAddRq requestID="1">
<TimeTrackingAdd>
<TxnDate>2017-08-23</TxnDate>
<EntityRef>
<FullName>Tarun Enest</FullName>
</EntityRef>
<CustomerRef>
<FullName>Bunn-O-Matic Corporation</FullName>
</CustomerRef>
<ItemServiceRef>
<FullName>LRMT</FullName>
</ItemServiceRef>
<Duration>0.3</Duration>
<PayrollItemWageRef>
<FullName>Hourly Techs</FullName>
</PayrollItemWageRef>
<ClassRef>
<FullName/>
</ClassRef>
<BillableStatus>Billable</BillableStatus>
</TimeTrackingAdd>
</TimeTrackingAddRq>
<TimeTrackingAddRq requestID="2">
<TimeTrackingAdd>
<TxnDate>2017-04-27</TxnDate>
<EntityRef>
<FullName>Tarun Enest</FullName>
</EntityRef>
<CustomerRef>
<FullName>Bunn-O-Matic Corporation</FullName>
</CustomerRef>
<ItemServiceRef>
<FullName>LRMT</FullName>
</ItemServiceRef>
<Duration>0.0</Duration>
<PayrollItemWageRef>
<FullName>Hourly Techs</FullName>
</PayrollItemWageRef>
<ClassRef>
<FullName/>
</ClassRef>
<BillableStatus>Billable</BillableStatus>
</TimeTrackingAdd>
</TimeTrackingAddRq>
<TimeTrackingAddRq requestID="3">
<TimeTrackingAdd>
<TxnDate>2017-08-23</TxnDate>
<EntityRef>
<FullName>Tarun Enest</FullName>
</EntityRef>
<CustomerRef>
<FullName>Bunn-O-Matic Corporation</FullName>
</CustomerRef>
<ItemServiceRef>
<FullName>LRMT</FullName>
</ItemServiceRef>
<Duration>0.0</Duration>
<PayrollItemWageRef>
<FullName>Hourly Techs</FullName>
</PayrollItemWageRef>
<ClassRef>
<FullName/>
</ClassRef>
<BillableStatus>Billable</BillableStatus>
</TimeTrackingAdd>
</TimeTrackingAddRq>
<TimeTrackingAddRq requestID="4">
<TimeTrackingAdd>
<TxnDate>2017-04-27</TxnDate>
<EntityRef>
<FullName>Tarun Enest</FullName>
</EntityRef>
<CustomerRef>
<FullName>Bunn-O-Matic Corporation</FullName>
</CustomerRef>
<ItemServiceRef>
<FullName>LRMT</FullName>
</ItemServiceRef>
<Duration>0.1</Duration>
<PayrollItemWageRef>
<FullName>Hourly Techs</FullName>
</PayrollItemWageRef>
<ClassRef>
<FullName/>
</ClassRef>
<BillableStatus>Billable</BillableStatus>
</TimeTrackingAdd>
</TimeTrackingAddRq>
<TimeTrackingAddRq requestID="5">
<TimeTrackingAdd>
<TxnDate>2017-04-27</TxnDate>
<EntityRef>
<FullName>Tarun Enest</FullName>
</EntityRef>
<CustomerRef>
<FullName>Bunn-O-Matic Corporation</FullName>
</CustomerRef>
<ItemServiceRef>
<FullName>LRMT</FullName>
</ItemServiceRef>
<Duration>0.0</Duration>
<PayrollItemWageRef>
<FullName>Hourly Techs</FullName>
</PayrollItemWageRef>
<ClassRef>
<FullName/>
</ClassRef>
<BillableStatus>Billable</BillableStatus>
</TimeTrackingAdd>
</TimeTrackingAddRq>
<TimeTrackingAddRq requestID="6">
<TimeTrackingAdd>
<TxnDate>2017-04-27</TxnDate>
<EntityRef>
<FullName>Tarun Enest</FullName>
</EntityRef>
<CustomerRef>
<FullName>Bunn-O-Matic Corporation</FullName>
</CustomerRef>
<ItemServiceRef>
<FullName>LRMT</FullName>
</ItemServiceRef>
<Duration>0.0</Duration>
<PayrollItemWageRef>
<FullName>Hourly Techs</FullName>
</PayrollItemWageRef>
<ClassRef>
<FullName/>
</ClassRef>
<BillableStatus>Billable</BillableStatus>
</TimeTrackingAdd>
</TimeTrackingAddRq>
<TimeTrackingAddRq requestID="7">
<TimeTrackingAdd>
<TxnDate>2017-08-22</TxnDate>
<EntityRef>
<FullName>Tarun Enest</FullName>
</EntityRef>
<CustomerRef>
<FullName>Travel</FullName>
</CustomerRef>
<ItemServiceRef>
<FullName>LRMT</FullName>
</ItemServiceRef>
<Duration>0.4</Duration>
<PayrollItemWageRef>
<FullName>Hourly Techs</FullName>
</PayrollItemWageRef>
<ClassRef>
<FullName>Dallas</FullName>
</ClassRef>
<BillableStatus>Billable</BillableStatus>
</TimeTrackingAdd>
</TimeTrackingAddRq>
</QBXMLMsgsRq>`enter code here`
</QBXML>
```

Please help me to over come the issue.
Can Any one provide me the sample code for this how to create a web service for this.
How to return a response from Quickbook webconnector?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39347578/1531971 https://stackoverflow.com/q/39253572/1531971 etc.  This is pretty much a duplicate -- you have to use the provided validator and figure it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [0x80040400: QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39253572/0x80040400-quickbooks-found-an-error-when-parsing-the-provided-xml-text-stream)