# QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream while passing values

Tags: python, odoo, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have been working on QuickBooks integration with python, While creating values on QB desktop from python,I am facing this error "QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream".
My xml input is like

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?qbxml version="8.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <ItemInventoryAddRq>
      <ItemInventoryAdd>
        <Name>Pencil</Name>
        <IncomeAccountRef>
          <FullName>Other Expenses</FullName>
        </IncomeAccountRef>
        <AssetAccountRef>
          <FullName>Inventory Asset</FullName>
        </AssetAccountRef>
        <COGSAccountRef>
          <FullName>Cost of Goods Sold</FullName>
        </COGSAccountRef>
      </ItemInventoryAdd>
    </ItemInventoryAddRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

I need to know, why is this error occuring and how to overcome this error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347578/quickbooks-found-an-error-when-parsing-the-provided-xml-text-stream)

Comment: That doesnot answer my issue,it is php and I am using Python@KeithPalmerJr.

Comment: It will be a bit difficult to figure out for python, as the documentations are for c#.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the validator application `qbValidator.exe` shipped with QB SDK to get more details about the error. You can find help installing and locating that on your computer from here: https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/article/QBXML-Validator.

Comment: Yes I have installed the validator@Veikko